# Match every message in a multiline log file using regex

Tags: java, regex, logging, stack-trace

I have this multiline log file:

```
INFO 2017-07-01 12:01:56,987 [Thread-1] Class1:15 This is the message 1
DEBUG 2017-07-01 12:01:56,987 [Thread-1] Class2:15 This is the message 2 
  that is multiline!
WARN 2017-07-01 12:01:56,987 [Thread-1] Class3:15 This is a warn message
ERROR 2017-07-01 12:01:56,987 [Thread-1] Class4:15 This is an error with the stacktrace...
my.packkageName.MyException: exception!
   at my.packkageName.Class4.process(Class4.java:11)
   at ...
INFO 2017-07-01 12:01:56,987 [Thread-1] Class1:15 This is another INFO message
```

I want a regex that matches every single message in the log, in this way:

```
group 1: INFO 2017-07-01 12:01:56,987 [Thread-1] Class1:15 This is the message 1

group 2: DEBUG 2017-07-01 12:01:56,987 [Thread-1] Class2:15 This is the message 2 
  that is multiline!

group 3: WARN 2017-07-01 12:01:56,987 [Thread-1] Class3:15 This is a warn message

group 4: ERROR 2017-07-01 12:01:56,987 [Thread-1] Class4:15 This is an error with the stacktrace...
my.packkageName.MyException: exception!
   at my.packkageName.Class4.process(Class4.java:11)
   at ...
```

This regex is only for single line messages:

```
(?:ERROR|DEBUG|INFO|WARN).++
```

Comment: Did you add Pattern.MULTILINE or (?m). This option will match at the start and end of each line (otherwise match is at the start/end of the string).

Comment: Read lline by line and while a line does not start with any of these values append to the current record, else add the entry to list, start a new one. If the log is small and you load it into memory you may `split("(?m)^(?=ERROR|DEBUG|INFO|WARN)")`

Comment: @fg78nc yes, I'm testing it on regex101, with multiline option

Comment: This is best achieved by reading line by line, see starting type(info...error) and grab all lines until you see the next one. Regex based solution won't stand still IMO.

Comment: Please post your complete regex code.

Comment: For now is /(?:ERROR|DEBUG|INFO|WARN).++/gm

Comment: Agree with reading line by line. Sounds like the easiest, most reliable and the solution you can adapt the array to perfectly suit your needs.

Comment: I will try to find a regex solution in any case, I'll share it if I find it.

Comment: et voilà! found it.

Comment: There's Java code missing that runs that regex - you should add it. Further possible [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): your problem seems to be grouping a log file with messages possibly split in multiple lines. A regular expression _may_ be part of a solution but it does not help with the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution.

The regex to be used is the following:

```
/(?:DEBUG|INFO|ERROR|WARN)[\s\S]+?(?=DEBUG|INFO|WARN|ERROR)/gm
```

This match every "log message" that is contained between the words DEBUG, INFO, ERROR or WARN, in multiline way.

Comment: This is a regex that will highlight the right matches for you at an online regex tester. However, once you start using it with `Matcher#find()` you will eventually find out that the program is too slow. Or it crashes. Or the matches are not as expected because `DEBUG` appears somewhere inside a message. Or the file is too big to load into memory. We mean it, read the file line by line. Mastering regex means know when to use it and when not to.

Answer (score 0):

To load the logfile into a string and use regex to find the messages is probably not the most efficient way to process big logfiles.

But if you're fine with regex and also want to get that last message then you could do something like this:

```
 String logstr = "INFO 2017-07-01 12:01:56,987 [Thread-1] Class1:15 This is the message 1\n"
 + "DEBUG 2017-07-01 12:01:56,987 [Thread-1] Class2:15 This is the message 2 \n"
 + "  that is multiline!\n"
 + "WARN 2017-07-01 12:01:56,987 [Thread-1] Class3:15 This is a warn message\n"
 + "ERROR 2017-07-01 12:01:56,987 [Thread-1] Class4:15 This is an error with the stacktrace...\n"
 + "my.packkageName.MyException: exception!\n"
 + "   at my.packkageName.Class4.process(Class4.java:11)\n"
 + "   at ...\n"
 + "INFO 2017-07-01 12:01:56,987 [Thread-1] Class1:15 This is another INFO message ";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([A-Z]{4,}).+?(?=(?:^[A-Z]{4}|\\z))", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher messages = pattern.matcher(logstr);

while (messages.find()) {
  System.out.println("---"+ messages.group(1));      
  System.out.println(messages.group(0)); 
}
```

Because of the Pattern.DOTALL the `.*` also matches the line terminators.

And with the Pattern.MULTILINE the `^` also matches after any line terminator except at the end of input.

The `\z` marks the end of the input.